# finding users location in leaflet and set it on map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

i have a map that shows some markers on it . what i want to do is that if a user is from city `a` the map initiates on city `a` and if a user is from city `b` the map initiates from `b` . so now what i have is like below :

```
  var myMap = new L.Map('map', {
        maptype: 'dreamy',
        poi: true,
        traffic: true,
        center: [35.699739, 51.338097],
        zoom: 8
    });
```

according to the documentation i added center which is an array of latlong now i want to get the user location and set it instead of center .

Answer (score 0):

To get the user's location, you will need to use the [Javscript Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API).

Based on the example at [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp):

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        var myMap = new L.Map('map', {
            maptype: 'dreamy',
            poi: true,
            traffic: true,
            center: [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude],
            zoom: 8
        });
        
        // ... do more stuff with your map

    });
}
```

You will likely want to introduce some error handling in the above.

Comment: when i change my code like this the map breakes and wont load any more

Answer (score 0):

Alex T's answer fetches the user's location correctly, but it is not good practice to initialise the map in the `getCurrentPosition()` callback. If the map is already initialised elsewhere, this will overwrite the original map with a new one, which in Alex's example would not be accessible elsewhere in the code, since `myVar` is a local variable inside the callback.  If the map isn't already initialised, then it won't load at all if the geolocation fails or is blocked by the user.  Instead, it is better to initialise the map first with a default location, and then pan it to the correct place if geolocation succeeds:

```
var myMap = new L.Map('mapid', {
  maptype: 'dreamy',
  poi: true,
  traffic: true,
  center: [35.699739, 51.338097],
  zoom: 8
});

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => myMap.panTo([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]),
    (err) => console.warn(`Geolocation error (${err.code}): ${err.message}`),
    { timeout: 20000 } // Timeout in ms
  );
}
```

As an aside, when I tested my answer, I was getting strange error messages, until I remembered I had a browser plugin installed to hide my location from websites. Once I disabled that, it worked fine.  Also make sure that the code is running in a secure context (e.g. over `https` - see the [Geolocation API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) for more details.